# Sequence characterization of bounded sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

If $M$ is an arbitrary metric space, the following holds:

> $A\subseteq M$ is totally bounded $\Leftrightarrow$ Each sequence in $A$ contains a Cauchy subsequence.

Additionally, for $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric, the following is true:

> $A\subseteq M$ is totally bounded $\Leftrightarrow$ $A\subseteq M$ is bounded.

In short: Total boundedness can be characterized by Cauchy sequences; and in Euclidean spaces, total boundedness and boundedness are the same.

---

I am looking for a sequence property (let's call it $P$ for brevity), such that the following two statements be true:

- If $M$ is an arbitrary metric space, then:

  > $A\subseteq M$ is bounded $\Leftrightarrow$ Each sequence in $A$ contains a subsequence with property $P$.
- If $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $M$, then:

  > $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has property $P$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

In short: Boundedness should be characterizable by $P$ sequences and in Euclidean spaces $P$ sequences and Cauchy sequences should be the same.

---

**My question:**
What property should $P$ be, such that the above holds?

---

**My thoughts and what I have done so far:**
I think the following definition would do:

> $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has property $P$
>   $:\Leftrightarrow$ $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded and all Cauchy subsequences of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are [equivalent](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_Relation_on_Cauchy_Sequences).

(Figuratively, this means that a $P$ sequence has *at most* one accumulation point. However, since the metric space need not be complete, instead of accumulation points I use the equivalence of Cauchy sequences.)

Then:

- If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence which contains no Cauchy subsequence, then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ itself has property $P$ (because if there isn't a Cauchy subsequence all Cauchy subsequences are trivially equivalent).
- If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence which does contain a Cauchy subsequence, then this Cauchy subsequence has property $P$ (because all subsequences of a Cauchy sequence are equivalent Cauchy sequences).
- If every sequence in $A$ contains a subsequence with property $P$, then $A$ must be bounded or else an unbounded divergent sequence could be constructed which does not contain a subsequence with property $P$.

So: $A$ is bounded iff each sequence in $A$ contains a subsequence with property $P$.

Additionally, we have:

- In an arbitrary metric space every Cauchy sequence has property $P$.
- In $\mathbb{R}^n$ every bounded sequence and thus every $P$ sequence contains a Cauchy subsequence. One can show that then a $P$ sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

So: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, Cauchy sequences and $P$ sequences coincide.

I conclude that my definition for the property $P$ seems to work. However, I don't find this definition esthetically nice and I wonder if the $P$ property can be defined in a prettier way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be a nice property. Consider a space $X$ with the discrete metric. Then $X$ is bounded, but every sequence in $X$ is either divergent or eventually constant.

Comment: Well, yes. So for the discrete metric, my $P$ property and Cauchyness are equivalent to eventual constantness. How is that problematic/How does that show that there is no nice property?

Comment: But "each sequence in $X$ contains a subsequence that is eventually constant" is false so it is not equivalent to $X$ being bounded.

Comment: You're right! Something I'll have to think about; thank you. :-)

Comment: What I had in mind was something along the lines of "A sequence has property $P$ iff it is bounded and all Cauchy subsequences of this sequence are [equivalent](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_Relation_on_Cauchy_Sequences)." I think, that every bounded, divergent sequence has such a $P$ sequence; and each eventually constant sequence trivially, too. (Essentially, $P$ sequences are then the  sequences with "at most one accumulation point" (without talking about accumulation points, since the space need not be complete).